# Using iList to process items failing

Tags: c#, linq, generics

It would be great to have shorthand for processing every item in a list, in this case saving.

SO intead of

```
var people = MakePeople();
foreach (var person in people)
{
    session.Save(person);
}
```

we could use

```
var cards = MakeCards(deck);
cards.Select(session.Save);
```

But, that doesn't work.. Suggestions? Aggregate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select` uses lazy evaluation, so it won't work.

You're looking for `List<T>.ForEach`, or its [non-existent LINQ version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Comment: +1 Something like `MakePeople().ForEach(p => session.Save(p))`

Comment: Good comments in that article, but for this kind of case, where it really is tiny, i think the argument for having a .ForEach is easy enough.. It's not like were doing if statement without brackets (which I hate)

Comment: Feel free to make your own extension method.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Save()` has no return value. To use the method with `Select()`, it needs to have a return value.

In general, it's a bad idea to use LINQ with methods that have side effects (like `Save()`). When there are side-effects, the first method is certainly preferred. If MakePeople returns a concrete List, you could also try:

```
var people = MakePeople();
people.ForEach((p) => { session.Save(p); });
```

Answer (score 0):

List has a [`ForEach(Action<T> action)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You tried to create a Card -> Void mapping. Select is meant to convert one item to another type so you can convert a card collection to e.g. a cardnumber collection.
As the others have already mentioned List has a ForEach overload. But the general theme of the C# language designers (see [Eric Lipperts blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)) was to not provide such an extension method since foreach is clearer. It does not safe you an awful amount of typing so the benefit here is minmal. 
For refernce you can create an extension method like that does what you want with 3 lines of code.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action)
{ // argument null checking omitted
  foreach(T item in sequence) action(item);
}
```

**Nitpick Corner:** I did mean and write that (at least one influental) C# language designer did not want to introduce this extension method. Once it exists in the BCL it can be used by any .NET language.

Yours,
  Alois Kraus